# 'resize' window event only seems to fire on vertical resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to adjust a box width and height according to the following rules:

1. Whenever the window is resized, the box size needs to be recalculated
2. The box needs to be the height of the body with slightest margin, but no scrollbars
3. The box needs to be 1/2 as wide as it is high in pixels
4. I am restricted to HTML5, CSS3, and vanilla JS (no jQuery)

I think I've got a pretty good working model, that works except for a small annoyance. Resizing the browser horizontally only fires the resizeWindow() once, and only at the start. Once the first horizontal resize fires, no amount of horizontal resizing triggers an update to the box text. Resizing the window in the vertical direction causes the desired behavior.

I would like to see the text update (via the resizeWindow() call), even if the size of the box doesn't have to change.

Snippet only seems to work in full page mode :/

```js
function resizeWindow() {
  ht = window.innerHeight;
  wd = window.innerWidth;
  elPreview = document.getElementById("preview");
  elPreview.style.height = "98.5vh";
  elPreview.style.width = (ht / 2) + "px";
  elPreviewText = document.querySelector("#preview p");
  elPreviewText.textContent = "Width: " + (ht / 2) + ", Height: " + ht;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow, true);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_proto.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box" id="preview">
    <p>Preview</p>
  </div>
  <script src="index_proto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, I'm a nit wit. The problem wasn't the window resize event not firing on horizontal resize, it was my function not printing the actual width, and instead calculating what I printed from the height that didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the css `@media` to change the width and height of your elements.

For Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .DivElementClassName {
        width: 300px;
        margin-left:25%;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'width' is always relative to 'height', so I think I have to calculate and update with JS. I may be wrong, I haven't done much with @media or relative h/w in CSS. I know I could use a library, my code was working with jQuery, actually. But my customer didn't want to have jQuery on his site if this was the only reason for including it (which it was).

Comment: I would say this is a good shot at having window resizing work. but you could also put into your script a function that detects screen size and setts a height and width attribute on every resize, and you could get the current size and use percentages.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. This is just sample code, but the app I am doing this for is real.

Comment: @BrianAnderson it is definitely worth working more with @ media, there is a lot of documentation to find on it, and you can almost use it as an if statement for your css, so your mobile apps could be a totally different colour for example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function resizeWindow() {
  ht = window.innerHeight;
  wd = window.innerWidth;
  elPreview = document.getElementById("preview");
  elPreview.style.height = "98.5vh";
  elPreview.style.width = (ht / 2) + "px";
  elPreviewText = document.querySelector("#preview p");
  elPreviewText.textContent = "Width: " + wd + ", Height: " + ht;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeWindow, true);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index_proto.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box" id="preview">
    <p>Preview</p>
  </div>
  <script src="index_proto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As I said above, please disregard. Some chucklehead of a programmer (me) was putting a number that would never change into an output that he expected to change.